# error message: Database X has not been opened yet

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I have for example 2 servers: A and B
On Server A I created a Lotus Agent in which I select documents from a view and copy that to Server B. When I run this agent manually from Server A then it works. But when I schedule the agent then I get an error on this line of code:

```
Call toDatabase.Open("CN=B","dasdar.nsf")

14-02-2017 09:20:11   AMgr: 'Administrator/as' is the agent signer of agent 'copyDocumentsToB' in 'dasdar.nsf'
14-02-2017 09:20:11   AMgr: 'Agent 'copyDocumentsToB' in 'dasdar.nsf' will run on behalf of 'Administrator/as'
14-02-2017 09:20:11   AMgr: Agent 'copyDocumentsToB' in database 'dasdar.nsf' signed by 'Administrator/as' is running in Full Administrator mode
14-02-2017 09:20:11   AMgr: Agent ('copyDocumentsToB' in 'dasdar.nsf') error message: Database CN=B!!dasdar.nsf has not been opened yet
```

Does it has something to do with access rights? My knowledge about IBM Notes administration is not very good. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add server A to server B's "**Trusted servers**" field on [server document's security tab](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_settingupnotesuserdominoserverandinternetusera_t.html).

Comment: On server B I have at Configuration > All server documents > Server A  
and then under the security tab I have this setting: Access server:  All users can access this server
But still same error.

Comment: Not "Access server" but "Trusted servers". This is the last field on security tab.

Comment: And look in the server document for server B, not the server document for server A.

Comment: Explanation: When you run it manually, it is actually *you* running it, not server A running it. It runs with your identity and therefore your permissions. When it actually runs on server A, it runs with the identity of server A, but it presents the identity of the agent signer to server B, Since server B didn't actually validate the signature itself, it has to trust that server A is telling the truth about the signer's identity. It only does that if server A is listed in its (server B's) server document as a Trusted Server. That's why you need to do what Knut has told you.